# A new-bie clarification on pexpect module

Tags: python, pexpect

I was going through the pexpect documentation and it said You can call the run() function to execute a command and return the output

so i did the following but it errored out. Am i missing something here?

```
>>> pexpect.run('pwd')
'/home/vijay\r\n'
>>> pexpect.run('cd /home')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 219, in run
    child = spawn(command, maxread=2000, logfile=logfile, cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 429, in __init__
    self._spawn (command, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 516, in _spawn
    raise ExceptionPexpect ('The command was not found or was not executable: %s.' % self.command)
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: cd.
>>>
```

I'm writing a script on which I download a git repository and wanted to perform cd (to that repository) and then pass on some command. so I have decided to use pexpect module since it provides interactive console

Let me know if I'm missing anything here?

Thanks,
-Vijay

Comment: cd is not a command in linux, it's a builtin function form your shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cd is a builtin function of your shell. You can run whatever command you want to do in whatever directory you want to using the run() methods `cwd` keyword arg:

```
pexpect.run("pwd", cwd="/home")
```

For more information check the API docs at: http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Alternatively you can use Python's `os.chdir()` function to change the current working directory before you execute the pexpect `run` method:

```
os.chdir("/home")
pexpect.run("pwd")
```

See: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html